# Can I use require with webpack for external files?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack

I want to import some static files that may not exist. I want to modify these external static files and to load them in my app, but Webpack gives 'module not found'

My folder structure looks like this in dev:

- src

  - static

    - config

      - cfg.json
      - folder1

        - file1.js
      - folder2

        - file2.js
  - component

    - Main.js

and in production webpack build everything and then it copies the static assets, making the folder structure like this:

- config (with the same files and folders inside, but they may get deleted or changed afterwards)
- app.js
- styles, etc.

What I want to do is to require from the Main.js, the files from the config folder in the static assets.

The static assets may, or may not exist. So what I tried was to put 'require' in a try/catch block, in this case if the required files are not found, then I use another flow in the catch.

I can use require with this path in Main.js ('../static/config/cfg.json'), but then, Webpack bundles all this, so if I modify the files in the config folder in production, the changes are not seen in the app.

In production and in development I can access the static files at http://localhost:3000/config/cfg.json or http://localhost:3000/config/folder1/file1.js

I can use fetch but I don't know how to read the variable that is exported default in file1.js, I can read only the entire file as a string using a FileReader.

And with fetch the code seems really messy.
Is there any way to do this with require and choose the according path, without  Webpack throwing 'module not found'?

Example code

```
try {
    let config = require('../static/config/cfg.json'); // if the cfg.json doesn't exist go straight to catch

    if (!config.active) {
        // throw error
    }

    // continue flow and read the js files
    // if the js files don't exist go straight to catch
}
catch(e => {
    // follow another flow
})
```

As I said, this code works, but if I modify anything in production in the static files, the changes are not seen, as Webpack requires the files that it bundled.

I expected to see the changes made to my external files, but instead Webpack requires the static files that it build.

Thank you in advance!

Edit: ---added webpack config entry ---

```
// ------------------------------------
// Entry Points
// ------------------------------------


// config.clientDir is the 'src' folder
// main.js is a file located in the 'src' folder, where React.DOM is called.
// so APP_ENTRY_PATH = 'src/main.js'

// config.compiler.publicPath = /app-name/ui // in this format...

const APP_ENTRY_PATH = paths.base(config.clientDir) + '/main.js';

webpackConfig.entry = {
  app: __DEV__ ?
    [APP_ENTRY_PATH, `webpack-hot-middleware/client?path=${config.compiler.publicPath}__webpack_hmr`] :
    [APP_ENTRY_PATH],
  vendor: config.compiler.vendor
};
```

Comment: can you please add the section concerning `entry` in your `webpack.config.js` ??

Comment: added the entry from the webpack.config.js :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because I didn't find a way with webpack, I modified the files from JS extension to JSON and I used fetch to get the JSON data.

See this for more details:

[HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54685597/read-exported-variable-from-remote-js-file)