# Read exported variable from remote js file

Tags: javascript, async-await

I have a javascript file that I need to read. I managed to read it as a String using FileReader, but I want to read the object that is exported in that file.

This is how my file looks:

```
const carsColor = {
    audi: 'blue',
    bmw: 'black',
};

export default carsColor;
```

Read it as a String:

```
loadFile = async () => {
    try {
        const response = await fetch(PATH_TO_FILE);
        const blob = await response.blob();
        let read = new FileReader();
        read.onload = function() {
            console.log(read.result); // read.result returns the entire file as a string
        };
        read.readAsBinaryString(blob); 
    }
    catch(e) {
        console.log(e);
    }
}
```

Is there a way to get the carsColor object from the file?

Thanks.

Comment: have you tried the import statement?

Comment: Can import be used with an url to the file? As the file may or may not exist so importing a non existing file gives me 'Module not found' with webpack.

Comment: This is what I'm talking about: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54679716/can-i-use-require-with-webpack-for-external-files

Comment: can you change the file format?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your file to return only json and parse it

the file

```
{
    audi: 'blue',
    bmw: 'black',
}
```

the load function

```
loadFile = async () => {
    try {
        const response = await fetch(PATH_TO_FILE);
        const blob = await response.blob();
        let read = new FileReader();
        read.onload = function() {
            console.log(JSON.parse(read.result)); 
        };
        read.readAsBinaryString(blob); 
    }
    catch(e) {
        console.log(e);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this. I thought about modifying my files from js to json, but I need to see if it's a good solution at this point. If I don't find a different solution with js files I'll convert them to json.

Comment: In the end I converted the js files to json.

But I didn't use `response.blob()`, but `response.json()`. So I didn't need a `FileReader`, I got the json data right away.

Answer (score 0):

The [Fetch API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API) does not load JS modules, but files. It does not evaluate your JavaScript file.

I would instead use a bundler for the source code (such as [webpack](https://webpack.js.org/)). Then you'll be able to use your JavaScript module with [`require()`](https://nodejs.org/api/modules.html#modules_require_id):

```
// either this
const carColors = require('./carColors');
// or this
import carColors from './carColors';

console.log(carColors.audi);
```

Comment: I can't use require, as the carColors file may or may not exist. And webpack gives me 'Module not found' even if I require in a try catch block. Please see my other question for more info: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54679716/can-i-use-require-with-webpack-for-external-files